# About mysql select and update nesting has a data error trouble

Tags: mysql, sql

[this is table record_t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWhNx.png)  I want to update the contents of the query in select to the m_sum field of the table in record_t, but it seems that there is something wrong with the data.

```
UPDATE record_t INNER JOIN
       (SELECT timestampdiff( MINUTE, b_time, e_time )*user_d.u_price AS mon 
        from record_t,user_d
        WHERE record_t.U_data=user_d.u_id;
       ) c
       ON record_t.User_id = c.user_id 
    SET record_t.m_sum = c.mon;
```

I am not a friend of a native English country, I hope to understand.

Comment: You mean need an update with joins ...?

Comment: Yes,But the updated data is not correct.

Comment: You needt to tell us what's is `not correct`

Comment: please share your table details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE record_t r INNER JOIN
       user_d u
       ON r.U_data = u.u_id
    SET r.m_sum = timestampdiff(minute, b_time, e_time  * u.u_price) ;
```